# Where did FacebookOAuthClient go?

Tags: oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

I just "upgraded" to 6.1.0 of the c# SDK and found that the FacebookAuthClient has been removed. I checked the commit log on github and there's not much info there.

Does anyone know how you are supposed to authenticate with the latest version of the SDK?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It has been removed.

Starting with v6 you can now use it with normal `FacebookClient.Get()` method. http://csharpsdk.org/docs/faq.html

**How do I get a Facebook Application Access Token?**

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new { 
    client_id     = "app_id", 
    client_secret = "app_secret", 
    grant_type    = "client_credentials" 
});
```

**How do I exchange code for access token?**

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new {
    client_id     = "app_id",
    client_secret = "app_secret",
    redirect_uri  = "http://yoururl.com/callback",
    code          = "code"      
});
```

**How do I extend the expiry time of the access token?**

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new {
    client_id         = "app_id",
    client_secret     = "app_secret",
    grant_type        = "fb_exchange_token",
    fb_exchange_token = "EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN"
});
```

Comment: @prabir you mean **FacebookOAuthClient** has been removed? so for the recent facebook api upgrade, I would have to change to **FacebookClient** to let it work? I've reviewed an old coding from my friends and thinking that you might be able to help if you don't mind. [facebooklogindialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473199/facebook-v2-2-login-c-sharp)