# facebook v2.2 login C#

Tags: c#, facebook, visual-studio-2010, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I would like to code for a FacebookLoginDialog.cs programmed in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate in C#. As you may know, Facebook has upgraded its API to v2.2 and most of the information I find online is v2.0 which I am not sure if it is the same.

I tried looking at [Facebook v2.0 Login with C# facebook sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399818/facebook-v2-0-login-with-c-sharp-facebook-sdk) but I could not access the link provided in it and it's v2.0.

And everytime I run my code, I will face this problem when I get to facebook login.

[image]

The code is given by my friend but she did it one or two years back before the facebook api upgraded recently. There is no URL (or uri) in my friend's coding. but it works for her previously when she started coding.

I have no access to the app ID site that was created. I have created a new app ID but to no avail.

Please help! I am really in need of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to solve this problem. The problem doesn't lies on the coding but the facebook developer site.

https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=542958419109491

Just enable the "Embedded browser OAuth Login" button and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the site Url you have mentioned at the Facebook developer section.

I think problem may arise only for two reason

1> Incorrect Url at facebook developer site

2> navigateUrl parameter should be same when you send code for access token.

Comment: you mean the URL that I input into the facebook developer site for app ID? If so, I haven't got a chance to create an app ID.

Comment: this coding was done one or two years back before facebook upgraded its api. i'm really not sure if it affects.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the appid used one or two years back is not able to be used in this case? I am still appealing to facebook to create an app ID tho.